# Custom 12 V DC motor control with ESP8266 without PWM

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, pwm, dc-motor, i2c

**Scenario**

*(you might want to skip the lengthy back-story)*

I'm trying to integrate my home ventilation system with my home automation. It currently consists of ten fans with ceramic heat recovery elements built into the wall and a central control unit. The control unit has four settings to control the airflow (off, 1, 2, 3).

The control unit has two 3-wire connectors, "forward" and "reverse". So five fans pull air in while the other five push air out. This is reversed after a while for heat recovery.

[image: Control unit]

My goal is to control each fan individually with a per-fan control.

The "interface" between control unit and fan works like this:

- each fan is connected with three wires: 12 V, GND, Control
- 12 V is always on
- control is a DC voltage between 0-12 V, **not PWM**
- control has a very low current (< 150 µA)
- control 0 V is full reverse, 12 V is full forward
- there is a neutral zone around 5 V turning the fan off

**Prototype**

My prototype is actually working quite well. Basically I branch 12 V to an AMS1117 to power an ESP8266 with 3.3 V. PWM signal on GPIO -> RC circuit for smoothing -> LM358 op-amp to amplify the voltage to up to 12 V. This new control signal drives the fan speed.

[image]

**Problem**

I am not satisfied with the RC + LM358 setup. It requires a lot of fine tuning to get a good bias point for both elements. And it depends on the tolerance value of the resistors and capacitors used. (... and it's a lot of soldering I'll have to do for ten individual controls). I don't want to risk damaging the fans by just applying PWM to them since I assume that they contain additional electronics.

**Questions**

- Is there a better solution to get a clean 0 - 12 V DC voltage without RC + opamp?
- My preferred solution would be an I2C module with a "0 - 100%" setting that guarantees the selected voltage. Is there such a module?
- What kind of built-in motor control am I communicating with?

Comment: You can buy a I2C DAC with a 12V output, or a DAC with a lower output and scale it properly with an opamp (although that requires more soldering). I don't know any part numbers for a 12V DAC off the top of my head but I've seen ones go up to 10V, so 12V isn't too much of a stretch.

Comment: Given the reasonably high input impedance it is possible you could use half bridge FET IC motor drivers (something like a TB6612) to make 12v PWM and then RC filter that.  But a DAC may be more deterministic and quieter in terms of not radiating PWM overtones.